# Why does my Wi-Fi channel rapidly change?

Tags: wireless-networking, aircrack-ng

I am trying to hack into my wifi for kicks, but my Wi-Fi channel keeps changing, like every few seconds.

I use the command: airodump-ng wlan0mon, and the channel in the top left corner keeps changing. It is impossible to brute force my way into the wifi if my channel keeps changing.

Answer (score 2):

The channel in the upper left corner isn't your WiFi's channel, it is the channel airodump-ng is currently listening to.airodump-ng needs to switch between channels to detect all available WiFi networks which are then listed in the list below and in that list your WiFi's channel is in the "CH" column of your Wifi access point's row (you can identify your row by looking at the "ESSID" column).
Now after you got your channel you can passively scan your network by using the "-c yourchannel" parameter:
`airodump-ng -c 10 wlan0mon`